# how does the returned function of JavaScript debounce function get all parameters through arguments

Tags: javascript, debouncing

generally for js debounce function, a simple implement goes like

```
function debounce(func, wait) {
  let timerId = null;
  return function (...args) {
  console.log('args',args);
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    timerId = setTimeout(() => func.apply(this, args), wait);
  }
}
```

and when you use it, you can do things like

```
var random = function() {console.log(arguments)};
var test = debounce(random, 1000);
test(1,2,3);
```

my question is, how does the returned function inside debounce function can get all attributes that gets passed into test function (here being 1,2,3) through arguments object? I feel like it might have to do with closure, but can anyone explain?

I've also created a jsFiddle for simpler view
https://jsfiddle.net/u4n07veb/22/

Another question would be in this js fiddle, my console.log args can print 1,2,3, since 1,2,3 is what I pass to test function, but would it also be possible to get 4,5,6 inside the debounce function? Since 4,5,6 is the parameters I pass to the callback function of the debounce function?

Answer (score 0):

Though the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) special object does exist in JavaScript, in the implementation of debounce above the function arguments are instead retrieved via a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

The difference is minimal - `arguments` is not a true `Array` but instead an `Array`-like object, whereas the `...args` rest parameter method will retrieve an actual `Array` - but it's one worth mentioning.

The actual passing through of these arguments happens when [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) is called, which allows a function to be called with a given value of `this` and a specified array of arguments. It's a sibling to the similar [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), which takes each argument to passed through as a separate parameter.

So in your example, you call `test(1, 2, 3)` and that executes the function that was returned by `debounce(random, 1000)`. That function gets its arguments as an `Array` via the `...args` rest parameter, and then passes that array through to the `random` function via `func.apply(this, args)`.

To answer your question about passing a different set of parameters through, I recommend you try it and see. But the answer is yes: with this setup the debounced function is able to pass through any number of arguments.

[Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) aren't directly relevant to how the arguments are passed through here. They are relevant in a different way, however, in that the `timerId` variable created when `debounce` is called is kept in a closure so that later attempts to call the debounced function will access it again, which is what allows the innards of this `debounce` implementation to clear the timeout it had created during its previous execution.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer! The point I'm suffering with is that why the returned function inside debounce can get all passed-in arguments through arguments object. I mean I know what arguments object is and how it works, but I just couldn't wrap my head around why would the returned function inside debounce can get it... maybe because when I call test(1,2,3), the returned function inside debounce is getting called with parameters 1,2,3?

Comment: When you call `test(1, 2, 3);` you are calling the function returned by `debounce`. That function collects all its arguments via a rest parameter, `...args`, which is then passed to the original function via `func.apply(this, args)`. Then that original function is able to access the same arguments that were passed through here with `args` by using its internal `arguments` object.